Change printer settings for the default printer (no printdocument) in C#
I have an external application which has one printer selected.
From C#, I want to change settings for this specific printer like page size and orientation, but I do not want (or can) print a document with that settings.
I just want to change the default settings of the printer, so that next time the external application triggers a print, it uses the modified page size and orientation
I found PrinterSettings class which allows me to GET all of this attributes, but I couldn't find out how to SET these values perisistently.
Any ideas?

No, this link just shows how to modify windows registry for internet explorer print, that does not help for other applications.

Where is your code going to run?  Is it on the same system that is running the external application? How is the external application accessing the printer? Is it a network printer or local printer to that system? Why do you need to change these settings programmatically? I'm sure there's a reason that you can't just change the defaults manually and have it "stick' but it's not clear from your question what that is. How often will your code change these defaults? One-time? Periodically? When there's a document in the print queue? Is there a chance the settings will be overwritten elsewhere?

I tried to provide an answer (or at least workaround), but it feels like there might be an XY problem going on here.

@NotTheDr01ds
My code is running on the same system, deployed automatically from a DevOps pipeline - so no possibility and not desired to do anything manually. The external application - which is out of my control - has a certain printer set as default, but no printer settings defined. Depending on how the machine was left off, the printer settings for that specific printer may or may not be ok. So each time (periodically) the code runs, it needs to ensure that the printer settings are set correctly. When defining settings, there is nothing in the printer queue.
